# MySql Query regarding use of TOP command

Tags: mysql

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'(2) from empdata where empid='E-713''` at line 1

```
mysql> delete TOP(2) from empdata where empid='E-713';  
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+---------+  
| id    | name   | height | salary | age  | city    |  
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+---------+  
| E-713 | Rajat  |   5.11 | 25000  |   25 | jaipur  |  
| E-720 | Ritesh |    5.8 | 30000  |   27 | Delhi   |  
| E-711 | Javed  |    5.7 | 23000  |   25 | kashmir |  
| E-715 | Puneet |    5.1 | 20000  |   27 | Noida   |  
| E-713 | Rajat  |   5.11 | 25000  |   25 | jaipur  |  
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+---------+
```

How can I get nth highest salary using top command in MySql. although my syntax is correct as per my knowledge but on pressing enter the above error flashed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

MySQL does not support `SELECT TOP`.  That is usually associated with SQL Server.

It does support `LIMIT`, so you could write:

```
delete ed
    from empdata ed
    where empid = 'E-713'
    limit 2;
```

However, this is very dangerous, because it deletes two *arbitrary* rows.  In almost all cases, you want an `ORDER BY`:

```
delete ed
    from empdata ed
    where empid = 'E-713'
    order by ??
    limit 2;
```

This is true whether you are using `TOP` or `LIMIT`.